# I need to cancel the Timer started in a service class from MainActivity, but get null reference exception

Tags: java, android, timer, nullpointerexception, timertask

I have a service type class which starts a timertask in onCreate method and I need to stop the timer from MainActivity when user press the button. I know I have to keep the reference to the timer in my service, but I cannot figure out how to do that and need some help, please!

please take a look at my code

```
package com.example.timertest;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button = findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);
        startService(new Intent(this, TimeService.class));

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v.getId() == R.id.button){
            // i need here to call mTimer.cancel() in TimeService.class
            //
        }
    }
}
```

// and here is the TimeService.java

```
package com.example.timertest;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.widget.Toast;


import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class TimeService extends Service {
    public Timer mTimer;
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    long NOTIFY_INTERVAL = 60 * 1000 * 1; // 1 min

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        if (mTimer != null) {
            mTimer.cancel();
        } else {
            mTimer = new Timer();
        }
        mTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new RefreshDataTimerTask(), 0, NOTIFY_INTERVAL);
    }

    class RefreshDataTimerTask extends TimerTask {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            mHandler.post(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getDateTime(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
        }

        private String getDateTime() {
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("[yyyy/MM/dd - HH:mm:ss]");
            return sdf.format(new Date());
        }
    }
}
```

//and service registered in manifest

```
<service android:name=".TimeService"/>
```

I have tried to call the mTimer.cancel(), but got a null reference, because seems I have created a new instance of the service class.

This example shows a Toast with date and time each minute, i want when for example 15 seconds have past and i press the button, the timer to be canceled and to start counting 60 seconds again from the beginning. Inside this service i have many other things like notifications,channels, shared preferences and so on, so it will be good if i can operate only with the timer object.

Comment: from where you call cancel timer ?

Comment: i need to call from from button click event, but i don't know how to reference the mTimer object

Comment: have look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177847/how-to-get-the-service-object-inside-activities)

Comment: Your link is useless, this is not my case, anyway thanks for it. I have found the solution thanks to Oleg Golomoz

Answer (score 1):

Take a look on this [API documentaion](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) and [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services). There is example of how to `bind` service to activity after what you can get direct access to service methods.

After successful binding you can add method inside your service to stop the timer:

```
public void stopMyTimer() {
    mTimer.cancel();
}
```

And call this method from `Activity`

Comment: Thank you, but i do not want to stop the service if possible. I just want to stop the timer where it is and restart the timer only for a new counting period. I have other things inside service too which have nothing in common with the problem with the timer.

Comment: Thank you, your answer and links have solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be best practice, but you can access public values by directly referring to the class:

```
TimeService.mTimer.cancel()
```

Which should work because Services function similarly to Singletons, in that each call of startService should be calling the same instance.

Comment: This is not working, mTimer is not visible from MainActivity, despite it is declared public. Solving the case is far more complicated, look at the previous answer by Oleg Golomoz. That was the correct solution in my case.